# $t=0$ and $x=0$ for the equation: $\frac{dx}{dt}=(2-x)(x+1)$? what is the differential equation and obtain an expression for x in terms of t.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

$t=0$ and $x=0$ for the equation: $\frac{dx}{dt}=(2-x)(x+1)$? what is the differential equation and obtain an expression for x in terms of t and what happens to the value of x when t becomes larger. this is the full question I was able to solve the fist part which was $\frac{1}{(2-x)(x+1)}$ and I will attach it below but I can figure out how to continue the question any help is much appreciated. I know the answers are $x=2(e^{3t}-1)/e^{3t}+2$ and x arrow to 2 but can get to it.
Any help is much appreciated .Thank you
[image]

Comment: How does your a) answer the question "what is the differential equation" ???

Comment: @Yves Daoust it doesnt thats the first part when they said solve $\frac{1}{(2-x)(x+1)}$ which was a but she don't get the other part b

Comment: @Emily: expecting the OP's answer.

Comment: @Yves Daoust emily is right that is what it means

Answer (score 2):

From the first part, by integration,

$$\frac13(\log(x+1)-\log(2-x))=t+c$$

or

$$\frac{x+1}{2-x}=Ce^{3t}$$ and using the initial condition,

$$\frac12=C.$$

Now solve for $x$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{dx}{(2-x)(x+1)} = dt$. This is known as "separable method". Can you take it from here?

Comment: I'd rather say *this is known as a separable equation*.

Answer (score 1):

Picking up from where you left off:

$$\int \frac{dx}{3(2-x)}+\int \frac{dx}{3(x+1)}=\int dt \Rightarrow \frac 13 \ln \frac {x+1}{2-x} + C =t \\
\ln \frac{x+1}{2-x}+C=3t \Rightarrow \ln \frac 12+C=0 \Rightarrow C= \ln 2 \\
\ln \frac {2(x+1)}{2-x}=3t \Rightarrow e^{3t}=\frac{2(x+1)}{2-x}=-2+\frac{6}{2-x} \\
e^{3t}+2=\frac{6}{2-x} \Rightarrow \frac{2-x}{6}=\frac{1}{e^{3t}+2} \Rightarrow 2-x=\frac{6}{e^{3t}+2} \Rightarrow x=2-\frac{6}{e^{3t}+2}.$$

Comment: how does this x in terms of t and what happens to the value of x when t becomes larger? necome x arrow to 2

Comment: That's right:

$$\lim_{t \to \infty} x=2$$

because the term involving $t$ goes to $0$.

Comment: and how does that become 2

Comment: What happens to $\frac{6}{e^{3t}+2}$ when $t$ gets large?

Comment: I mean it gets larger but how do you know by 2

Comment: The term that grows is in the denominator so the fraction doesn't get larger.  Use a calculator if you must to see what happens to the fraction as $t$ gets larger.